# Mongodb aggregate $project return null value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when i try to get the date of birth with $birth_date, the result returns empty. Can you help me? isn't there any way i can get to the $birth_date field in that area? I've tried the variables $user.birth_date and $$ROOT.user.birth_date, but they're empty.

```
$birth_date = null
```

```
return await likes.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "sender",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: { sending: database.Types.ObjectId(id), status: true }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                user: {
                    name: true,
                    age: { $dateDiff: { startDate: "$birth_date", endDate: "$$NOW", unit: "year" } },
                    photo: {
                        first: true,
                        second: true,
                        third: true
                    },
                    about: true
                },
                create_date: true
            }

        }
    ])
```

[Here is a picture of the query printout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Bhm.png)

Comment: Please give a sample doc for both the `likes` and `users` collections.  I am guessing `birth_date` is in `users` so after the `$lookup` it will part of an *array* name `user` containing docs .   Likely, `birth_date` will not be a top level field in the pipeline but rather `user.birth_date` but we'd have to see more to be sure.  Also:  Does that `$lookup` always return one and *only* one match into `users`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot .toArray() at the end:

```
return likes.aggregate(...).toArray()
```

Also, no reason to "await" the result. It will return the same promise for both cases